# Conflicting rules in htaccess prevents 404 page from bring displayed

Tags: .htaccess, web-development-server

i already have a condition to check for non-existing page and display 404 page accordingly. However, the rule doesn't works when i'm in sub-directory 'cms' due to a conflicting rule. How can i fix this? My code shown below:

```
#This worked fine  
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^ /404.html [L,NC]

#with this rule 404 would not show
#e.g. mywebsite.com/cms/non_existent.php would not show 404 page
RewriteRule ^events/  cms/callers.php [L]
RewriteRule ^event/(.*)/  cms/callingparty.php?eventid=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^cms/(.*)/(.*)/ cms/showpage.php?param1=$1&param2=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^cms/(.*)/ cms/showpage.php?param1=$1 [L]
```

Comment: What happenes when you type "domain/events/ ?

Comment: It will display the 404 page, but if i type "domain/cms/" it would just show a blank page. Sorry, i was away could not reply you earlier.